# How to set minimum number of characters for user password in django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I want to change the ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH in django-allauth. I tried ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 5 in settings.py and it is not working, Django is still saying that I need to enter 8 characters, like it is by default.

Here is my settings.py file:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'taggit',
    'django_summernote',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'user_account',
    'widget_tweaks',

]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project_blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project_blog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Django-allauth
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    #'/var/www/static/',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media_cdn')


SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    # Using SummernoteWidget - iframe mode
    'iframe': True,  # or set False to use SummernoteInplaceWidget - no iframe mode

    # Using Summernote Air-mode
    'airMode': False,

    # Use native HTML tags (`<b>`, `<i>`, ...) instead of style attributes
    # (Firefox, Chrome only)
    'styleWithTags': True,

    # Set text direction : 'left to right' is default.
    'direction': 'ltr',

    # Change editor size
    'width': '100%',
    'height': '480',

    # Authentication required
    'attachment_require_authentication': False,
}

EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

# Custom allauth settings
# Use email as the primary identifier
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email' 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# Make email verification mandatory to avoid junk email accounts
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory' 
# Eliminate need to provide username, as it's a very old practice
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
# Minimum password characters
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation), you need to specify `OPTIONS` dict together with built in django password validator, like this:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 5,
        },
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH is [deprecated](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes.html#id32). Use Django's own AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS setting.